# how to move to another layout in same tab using fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi everybody i am creating tabview by extending fragment activity and it is  displaying properly but in my first tab i have a listview when i click that view i need to move to another view but in the same tab how it can be done and i know how to create tabview by tabactivity but i dont know properly about using fragment activity along tabview so,if any tutorials link regarding tabview with fragment activity will be very helpfull .                   this is code

```
public class FragmeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {

private TabHost mTabHost;
private HashMap mapTabInfo = new HashMap();
private TabInfo mLastTab = null;

private class TabInfo {
     private String tag;
     private Class clss;
     private Bundle args;
     private Fragment fragment;
     TabInfo(String tag, Class clazz, Bundle args) {
         this.tag = tag;
         this.clss = clazz;
         this.args = args;
     }

}

class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

    private final Context mContext;

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public TabFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /** (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory#createTabContent(java.lang.String)
     */
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        return v;
    }

}
/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Step 1: Inflate layout
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Step 2: Setup TabHost
    initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
    }
}

/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
 */
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); //save the tab selected
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

/**
 * Step 2: Setup TabHost
 */
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    FragmeActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1", Tab1Fragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    FragmeActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", Tab2Fragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    FragmeActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", Tab3Fragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    // Default to first tab
    this.onTabChanged("Tab1");
    //
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}

/**
 * @param activity
 * @param tabHost
 * @param tabSpec
 * @param clss
 * @param args
 */
private static void addTab(FragmeActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
    // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
    String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

    // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
    // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
    // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
    tabInfo.fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (tabInfo.fragment != null && !tabInfo.fragment.isDetached()) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(tabInfo.fragment);
        ft.commit();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }

    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener#onTabChanged(java.lang.String)
 */
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    TabInfo newTab =  (TabInfo) this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    if (mLastTab != newTab) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (mLastTab != null) {
            if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
            }
        }
        if (newTab != null) {
            if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                        newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
            } else {
                ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
            }
        }

        mLastTab = newTab;
        ft.commit();
        this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be better to say what you want to see? Maybe people here don't use much the technology you propose (fragment)?

Comment: @gangnus  i want to move from one activity to another activity in the same tab

Answer (score 0):

[How does an activity in a tab knows it switch to another tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772694/how-does-an-activity-in-a-tab-knows-it-switch-to-another-tab)

[Android - Switch Tabs from within an Activity within a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541802/android-switch-tabs-from-within-an-activity-within-a-tab)

[Switch back to previously selected tab after the activity is recreated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032109/switch-back-to-previously-selected-tab-after-the-activity-is-recreated)

[Activity in TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697055/activity-in-tabhost) ( with a reference to a [tutorial](http://androidgenuine.com/?p=375) )